# git pull / git daemon over openssh failed

Tags: git, openssh

I have 2 linux kubuntu and funtoo:

My funtoo is an openvpn server. An openvpn tunnel is opened between us funtoo and kubuntu over a mobile network.

From kubuntu, I open a ssh session (directly, not over the vpn tunnel) on funtoo to start a git daemon with:
`git daemon --export-all --base-path=$PWD --verbose` (that's work fine locally)

and I try to `git pull` my repository (It was already well cloned). For this I use the gentoo local address to use vpn tunnel.

The git daemon brakes connection:

```
[20102] Connection from 10.100.0.10:40559
[20102] Extended attributes (18 bytes) exist <host=192.168.0.6>
[20102] Request upload-pack for '/GIT_REPO'
[19946] [20102] Disconnected
```

The git pull hangs after

```
"Compression of objects 100%"
```

And sometimes my ssh session also hangs.

I can re-open a new ssh session and I can ping my gentoo over the vpn tunnel: The mobile internet connection and ssh tunnel are not dead.

I think there is something wrong with my openvpn connection. But I don't know what.
Any idea ?

Comment: Probably better fits on Server Fault. I wonder if it is an MTU issue: How's other things work over the VPN? Anyhting else cause it to hang? I'm thinking maybe git is just generating a packet larger than most others and it doesn't make it to the other end because it is too big once encapsulated.

Comment: It's probably an MTU issue but I don't know if/how I can configure my vpn correctly. Note git pull over an ssh tunnel works fine (but I don't like this solution)